# How to achieve "Setter Injection with Map"

Tags: java, spring, dictionary, dependency-injection

I am new with Spring and trying to learn Spring
I am trying to implement Setter Injection with Map I did not have any idea how to achieve this I followed some tutorial but after writing the code I am getting an syntax error and I do not know how to fix this even in eclipse I am not getting any suggestion.

Please suggest me how to achieve this.

I have three file

```
Question.java Class
applicationContext.xml
TeatMain.java
```

**Question.java**

```
package com.varun.si.collection.map;

import java.security.KeyStore.Entry;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Question {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Map<String,String> answers;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public Map<String, String> getAnswers() {
        return answers;
    }
    public void setAnswers(Map<String, String> answers) {
        this.answers = answers;
    }
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Id :"+id+"\nName :"+name);
        System.out.println("Answers are....");


        Set<Entry<String, String>> set=answers.entrySet();  
        Iterator<Entry<String, String>> itr=set.iterator();

        while(itr.hasNext()){  
            Entry<String,String> entry=itr.next();  
            System.out.println("Answer:"+entry.getKey()+" Posted By:"+entry.getValue());  
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting error in these line

```
Set<Entry<String, String>> set=answers.entrySet();  

Entry<String,String> entry=itr.next();
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans  
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd"> 

<bean id="question" class="com.varun.si.collection.map.Question">
<property name="id" value="100"></property>
<property name="name" value="varun"></property>
<property name="answers">
<map>
<entry key=" Tera kya hoga re kaliya" value="Gabbar"></entry>
<entry key="" value="Basanti"></entry>
<entry key="Basanti in kutto ke samne mat nachna" value="Veru"></entry>
<entry key="Bhag dhano bhag aaj teri basanti ki izzat ka sawal hai" value="Basanti"></entry>
<entry key="Ye dosti hum nahi chorenge" value="Jay"></entry>
<entry key="ye hath mujhe de de gabbar" value="Thakur"></entry>

</map>

</property>
</bean>



</beans>
```

**TestMain.java**

```
package com.varun.si.collection.map;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;  
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;  
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;  
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;  

public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Resource resource=new ClassPathResource("com/varun/si/collection/map/applicationContext.xml");
        BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(resource);
        Question question=(Question)factory.getBean("question");
        question.display();


    }

}
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: @Erik Dolor The type KeyStore.Entry is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String, String>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following import in `Question.java` :

```
import java.security.KeyStore.Entry;
```

to this:

```
import java.util.Map.Entry;
```

You are using one class instead of another.

**EDIT**:

**To your first question**: it's necessary to use `Entry` because it's the best way to iterator over a `Set`.

**To your second question**, 
the error is saying that:

1. The bean declared in the xml is  `com.varun.si.collection.map.Question`
2. The class used in `com.varun.si.collection.Question` is used in `TestMain`

As you consider the posted code, there's no reference to a `com.varun.si.collection.Question` so I suppose there's another or other configuration.

I *suggest* you to put a:

```
import com.varun.si.collection.map.Question;
```

to **TestMain.java** and eventually remove import `com.varun.si.collection.Question` if you have it

Comment: Can you please explain me what is happening in this line   Set<Entry<String, String>> set=answers.entrySet();  Why do we need to take Entry ???

Comment: now I am getting this error log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.varun.si.collection.Question cannot be cast to com.varun.si.collection.map.Question
 at com.varun.si.collection.map.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:14)

Comment: It seems like the class you are using in TestMain is different than the bean declared in applicationContext.xml, but your code seems right. Do you have to Question classes?

Comment: I have posted every thing above...i guess this is creating problem com.varun.si.collection.Question cannot be cast to com.varun.si.collection.map.Question at

Comment: i got it . i was not specifying the correct absolute path TestMain.java Thanks